# Microsoft Purview - Scan rule sets, how to set Ignore patterns for folders containing a specific phrase

Tags: azure-purview

We are scanning an Azure Data Lake (Gen 2). In the scan results we get some folders that we don't want to appear in the asset register (inside collection) - for example, a backup folders (folders with name "_bck") as per the below:

[image]

Should I use option when I'm creating new scan rule sets, Ignore patterns ? And if so, how to set pattern to ignore all folders that have "* _bck *" in their name ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can scope your scan to specific folder choosing the appropriate folder while setting up the scan. In scan setup includes configuring the name of the scan, scope of scan, integration runtime, scan trigger frequency, scan rule set, and resource set uniquely for each data source per scan frequency. I don't understand why you want to configure Ignore patterns. Ignore patterns supports ignore the files not folder.